# Using a button in a table to remove that specific row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a diary to store my running times, dates and distances. I current have this which is a table with 3 columns of data and a button to append the information stored in the data fields to the next row of the table.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<head>

<title>Running Diary</title>
<link type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" href= "running.css"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> 
<script src ="running.js"></script>
</head>


<body>


<!-- Title at the top of page !-->
    <h1 id = "title"> Running Diary </h1>
</br>
</br>
</br>
<!-- Table containing text/date fields and the entries for a running diary. !-->
    <table id = "diary">

<!-- Column titles for the running diary !-->
        <thead id = "diaryHeader">
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Distance Ran (KM)</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            </th>
        </thead>

<!-- The table row that contains the text field and enter button for adding each entry to the diary !-->
        <tbody>
            <tr id = "diaryFields">
                <td> <input type="date" id="dateField"/></td>
                <td> <input type="number" id="distanceField" placeholder="Distance"/> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" id="timeField" placeholder="HH:MM:SS"/> </td>
                <td> <input type="submit" value="Add" id="diarySubmit"/>

            </tr>

</table>




</body>
```

and the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

//This handles the click function for diarySubmit button
    $("#diarySubmit").on('click', function(){
//Taking values from each textbox
        var distanceRan = $('#distanceField').val(); 
        var timeRan = $('#timeField').val();
        var dateRan = $('#dateField').val();
//creating the new row to be added with a button to clear the entry 
        var new_row =  '<tr><td>'+distanceRan+'</td><td>'+timeRan+'</td><td>'+dateRan+'</td>'+'<td>'+'<button id="clearRow">Clear Entry'+'</button></td></tr>'
        $('#diary').append(new_row);
        });
});
```

How do I make the '#clearRow' button remove the table row that it is nested inside?

I have come up with this piece of code, but it doesn't work properly, any help please?

```
$('#clearRow').on('click', function(e){
   $(this).closest('tr').remove()
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDs should be unique. You should use classes instead:

```
<button class="clearRow">Clear Entry'+'</button>
```

Also, since your elements are being dynamically added, you should be using [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

```
$('#diary').on('click', '.clearRow', function(e){
    $(this).closest('tr').remove()
});
```

This way, the click will be bound to the `diary` table, which will check if you clicked on a `clearRow` button when the event bubbles up to the table.

Comment: Although I agree, an ID isn't an issue here because of `this`

Comment: I went to test it myself and it appears that you're right! Since jQuery is not using the selector in the usual way, it works fine to have an ID as a delegated event. Interesting indeed! [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/0awnqo81/)

Comment: I think this is the best answer though +1

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is help u

```
    $(document).ready(function(){   
      $("#diarySubmit").on('click', function(){
          var row_uniqe_id = Math.round(Math.random()*100000);
          var distanceRan = $('#distanceField').val(); 
          var timeRan = $('#timeField').val();
          var dateRan = $('#dateField').val();
          var new_row =  '<tr>\
                            <td>'+distanceRan+'</td>\
                            <td>'+timeRan+'</td><td>'+dateRan+'</td>\
                            <td><button onclick="javascript:$(\'tr.'+row_uniqe_id+'\').remove();">Clear Entry</button></td>\
                          </tr>';
          $('#diary').append(new_row);
      });
    });
```

Comment: you cant defined more than one element that have an id, id is uniqe in a html page. you can use class to do that because if u try to second or higher position ov the same id, javascript will execute first element that have same id

Comment: Can I ask why you put the "\" after 
"var new_row =  '<tr>"
is it just a visual preference for you, or does it serve a practical function?

Comment: backslash is use when u want to break line of string, say

Answer (score 0):

Compare

**This is work**

```
var new_row =  '<tr>\
                  <td>'+distanceRan+'</td>\
                  <td>'+timeRan+'</td><td>'+dateRan+'</td>\
                  <td><button onclick="javascript:$(\'tr.'+row_uniqe_id+'\').remove();">Clear Entry</button></td>\
                </tr>';
```

**This is work too**

```
var new_row =  '<tr>'
              +'    <td>'+distanceRan+'</td>'
              +'    <td>'+timeRan+'</td><td>'+dateRan+'</td>'
              +'    <td><button onclick="javascript:$(\'tr.'+row_uniqe_id+'\').remove();">Clear Entry</button></td>'
              +'  </tr>';
```

**This is Error**

```
var new_row =  '<tr>
                  <td>'+distanceRan+'</td>
                  <td>'+timeRan+'</td><td>'+dateRan+'</td>
                  <td><button onclick="javascript:$(\'tr.'+row_uniqe_id+'\').remove();">Clear Entry</button></td>
                </tr>';
```